# zip4j doesnot extract files with large extension

Tags: java, unzip, zip

Zip4j is not able to extract file in the zip which are having large extension when using

```
extractfile(filename,destination)eg.file with extension 0800_XXXXXXX:1000
```

Has anybody got a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably think that the problem is with the colon not the length of the extension.  Colon is not allowed to be part of a file name.